# Question about elementary set theory (related to database design theory)

Tags: elementary-set-theory

**Definition**:
Let $U$ and $D$ be sets. For $X, Y \subseteq U$ and $I \subseteq D^U(:=\{f \mid \text{$f$ is a map from $U$ to $D$}\})$, we define an 3-ary predicate $P(I, X, Y)$ as follows:
$$ P(I, X, Y) \text{ if and only if for every $s, t \in I, s|_X = t|_X$ implies $s|_Y = t|_Y$}.$$

Futhermore, for a family $F := \{(X_\lambda, Y_\lambda)\}_{\lambda \in \Lambda}$of pairs of subsets of $U$, we define a predicate $I \vDash F$ as follows:
$$ I \vDash F \text{ if and only if for every $(X, Y) \in F, P(I, X, Y)$}.$$

**Question**:
Let $U$ be a **finite** set, $D$ a set, $F :=\{(X_\lambda, Y_\lambda)\}_{\lambda \in \Lambda}$ a **finite** family of pairs of subsets of $U$, and $a \in U \setminus \cup_{\lambda \in \Lambda} (X_\lambda \cup Y_\lambda)$ and suppose $K (\subseteq U)$ satisfies that for any **finite** subset $I$ of $D^U$, $I \vDash F$ implies $P(I, K, U)$. Then $a \in K$?

Thank you in advance.

---

**To those who know database design theory**:
This question can be explained in the language of database design theory as follows:

$$ \text{
If $a$ is an attribute that does not occur in a set of functional dependencies $F$, does a  superkey $K$ always contain $a$?
}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, $a \in K$. If $|D| \leq 1$ it's trivial, so assume $d_0, d_1 \in D$ are distinct. Now let a $K$ be given and take two functions $I = \{f_0, f_1\}$ which agree except that $f_0(a) = d_0 \neq d_1 = f_1(a)$. Then $I \models F$, because $f_0|_Y = f_1|_Y$ holds for any $(X, Y) \in F$ since $a \notin Y$ by definition. It follows that $P(I, K, U)$. Since $f_0|_U = f_0 \neq f_1 = f_1|_U$ it follows that also $f_0|_K \neq f_1|_K$. But then we must have $a \in K$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It seems that "except that $f_0(a) = d_0 \neq d_1 = f_1(a)$" is correct, not "except that $f_0(a) = f_1(a)$", though it's just a trivial mistake.

Comment: As we can see from your proof, $a \in U \setminus \cup_\lambda(X_\lambda \cup Y_\lambda)$ was redundant, $a \in U \setminus \cup_\lambda Y_\lambda$ is sufficient.

Comment: @mochimochinoki Yep, thanks! Fixed it. (In cases like this, if you want to, feel free to edit the answer yourself, too, it's considered helpful and not at all rude.)

Answer (score 1):

I was able to prove $a\in K$ by myself, though the proof needs some knowledge of database design theory. I will share the outline of it.

---

By structural induction on Armstrong's rules, the following proposition can be proven easily.

**Proposition**: Let $U$ be a attribute set, $F = \{X_\lambda \rightarrow Y_\lambda\}_{\lambda \in \Lambda}$ a set of functional dependencies, and $A \in U \setminus \cup_{\lambda \in \Lambda} Y_\lambda$. Then for any functional dependency $X \rightarrow Y$ that can be derived by Armstrong's rules from  $F$ (hereinafter denote $F \vdash X \rightarrow Y$), $A \in Y$ implies $A \in X$.

Since if $K$ is a superkey, $F \vdash K \rightarrow U$ and $A \in U$,
this proposition leads to what we want easily by the soundness and completeness of Armstrong's rules.